# HttpContext.User value is null when using httpClient for calling WebApi method in Blazor

Tags: blazor, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am using httpClient to make web API calls but can't get the HTTP context user values while calling methods with the web API using the HTTP client. But I can get if call a method in using ajax request from js.

```
client httpClient = new HttpClient();
responseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(urlValue, httpContent);
```

in web API method

```
UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User) // returns null value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not authentified so you cannot have a user on server side :

```cs
client httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
// this is an anonymous request
responseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(urlValue, httpContent);
```

You must authenticate your request by registring a `HttpClient` and use the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` to authenticate each requests.

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;

...

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", 
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com/base"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
```

Read [ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly additional security scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more information