# No service for type ' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, class-library

I am currently working on a project that consists of sub-projects such as WebApp, API, and Client class library. (The project structure is shown below).
[Project Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw6bX.jpg)

Although the project is a web-based project, it uses windows Identity as authentication identity since it is an internal application. I implemented the authorization policy of the WebApp project without any problems by following the steps in the [implementation_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68399416/net-core-webapi-setting-default-authorization-policy-on-negotiate-windows-au).
Now I can control access using DataAnnotation in WebApp (ex. [Authorize(Roles = "Admin"]). If I add Authorization control on the API side, WebApp cannot access this API. This is because of HttpContext.User is null. I found the solution to this problem [solution_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349063/httpcontext-user-value-is-null-when-using-httpclient-for-calling-webapi-method-i). I adapted this solution to the project as below:

ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs in WebApp project:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAuraServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IModelDatabaseNamesProvider, StandardCasingModelDatabasesNamesProvider>();
        serviceCollection.Configure<RouteOptions>(routeOptions =>
        {
            routeOptions.ConstraintMap.Add(ModelDatabasesNameConstraint.Name, typeof(ModelDatabasesNameConstraint));
        });
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IModelMetadataProvider>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
            var modelName = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["model-name"].ToString();
            return new ModelMetadataProvider(modelName);
        });

        DateOnlyTypeConverter.AddAttributeToType();

        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<UploadRulesClient>("ServerAPI", (httpClient) =>
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["AuraApiClient:BaseAddress"]);
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<ScenarioZipFilesClient>("ServerAPI",(httpClient) =>
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["AuraApiClient:BaseAddress"]);
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        serviceCollection.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
            .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));


        var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
        };

        ClientJsonResponse.Configure(jsonSerializerOptions);
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(jsonSerializerOptions);
        serviceCollection.AddAuraDropzoneConfig(configuration);
        return serviceCollection;
    }
```

Startup.cs of WebApp:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuraServices(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "model-database", pattern: "{model-name:modeldatabasename}/{controller=ZipFiles}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            //endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

But this time I am getting No service for Type [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW3uX.jpg). How can I solve this problem? Where do you think I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: In `CreateClient` you are passing only `ServerAPI` as per official document it should contain `.CreateClient("{APP ASSEMBLY}.ServerAPI"));` You could [check here for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authentication-service-support-1)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

As you can see `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` is in namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication`. It is supposed to be used with Blazor WebAssembly apps and it attaches the access token to the authentication header of `HttpClient` requests. `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` depends on other services like `IAccessTokenProvider` which is responsible to return the access token. For example in web assembly `IAccessTokenProvider` default implementation retrieves the access token from browser session storage.

If you want to attach access tokens to your http requests your should probably implement your own `DelegatingHandler` instead of `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler`.

**Old answer:**

You have to register `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler`:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```